# Node.js - JSON object manipulation

Tags: json, node.js

I have a problem converting my JSON to desired format. I have something like this:

```
{ 
    "one:apple": "5",
    "one:orange": "10",
    "two:apple": "6",
    "two:orange": "11" 
}
```

and I would like to get:

```
[ 
    ["one","5","10"],
    ["two","6","11"]    
]
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Your desired format is not a valid data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your JSON is:

```
{ 
    "one:apple": "5",
    "one:orange": "10",
    "two:apple": "6",
    "two:orange": "11" 
}
```

and your desired JSON is:

```
[ 
    ["one","5","10"],
    ["two","6","11"]    
]
```

Then you can iterate over the keys of your object and add the values of the elements to another hash with shorter keys, and then convert that new hash to an array of arrays.

### Example

```
let json1 = `{
    "one:apple": "5",
    "one:orange": "10",
    "two:apple": "6",
    "two:orange": "11"
}`;

function convert(j) {
    let o = JSON.parse(j);
    let h = {};
    for (let k of Object.keys(o)) {
        let n = k.split(':')[0];
        if (!h[n]) h[n] = [];
        h[n].push(o[k]);
    }
    let a = Object.keys(h).map(k => [k].concat(h[k]));
    return JSON.stringify(a);
}

let json2 = convert(json1);

console.log('json1:', json1);
console.log('json2:', json2);
```

See: [**DEMO**](https://repl.it/FGCR)

### Example for Node 0.10

This should work on Node v0.10.x:

```
var json1 = '{\n' +
'    "one:apple": "5",\n' +
'    "one:orange": "10",\n' +
'    "two:apple": "6",\n' +
'    "two:orange": "11"\n' +
'}';

function convert(j) {
    var o = JSON.parse(j);
    var h = {};
    for (var k in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            var n = k.split(':')[0];
            if (!h[n]) h[n] = [];
            h[n].push(o[k]);
        }
    }
    var a = Object.keys(h).map(function (k) {
        return [k].concat(h[k]);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(a);
}

var json2 = convert(json1);

console.log('json1:', json1);
console.log('json2:', json2);
```

See: [**DEMO**](https://repl.it/FG0Q)

Comment: Hi - it works perfectly, but.... I forgot to add it must work on node 0.10.x - will appreciate if you could take a look once again

Comment: @mfpass Sy my updated answer for a version that should work on older Node.